# Rの古いパッケージのインストール

Tags: r

RでCRANにあがっているCBPSというパッケージがあるのですが、その中のIPWやDRという関数がアップデートされてなくなってしまったため旧パッケージをインストールしたいです。
旧旧：http://www2.uaem.mx/r-mirror/web/packages/CBPS/CBPS.pdf
旧：http://ftp.cs.pu.edu.tw/network/CRAN/web/packages/CBPS/CBPS.pdf
新：https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/CBPS/CBPS.pdf
調べてもアップデートの情報しか出てこないため困っております。よろしくお願い致します。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CRANはすべてCRANに載せられたパッケージを維持してます。

[CRAN](https://cran.r-project.org/) > [Packages](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/) > [Archive](https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive) > [CBPS](https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/CBPS/)

そこに好きのようなバージョンをダウンロードしてインストールできます。

- [旧旧(0.3)はここ](https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/CBPS/CBPS_0.3.tar.gz)
- [旧(0.7)はここ](https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/CBPS/CBPS_0.7.tar.gz)

しかも、[GitHubのCRANミラー](https://github.com/cran/CBPS/commits/master)で何がいつか変化されたか答えられます。

Comment: `> install.packages("https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/CBPS/CBPS_0.8.tar.gz")`

とすると

`Installing package into ‘/home/notebook/spark-1.6.0-bin-hadoop2.6/R/lib’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
Warning in install.packages :
  package ‘https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/CBPS/CBPS_0.8.tar.gz’ is not available (for R version 3.3.1)`

となってしまいインストールがうまくいかないです。R2.14以上だと大丈夫なはずですが。

Comment: @user87562残念。。。